# SSH Tunnel through proxychains

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, proxychains

I hope my question make sense

So I have a JumpServer that has a VPN connection to another subnet ex. 10.x.x.x. This subnet is only accessible via JumpServer. So I can connect to 10.x.x.x from my local machine by using socks proxy:

- `ssh root@JumpServer -D 9999`
- Add config on /etc/proxychains socks5 127.0.0.1 9999 then `proxychains ssh root@10.x.x.x`

When I perform proxychains SSH, the local address of 10.x.x.x is 192.x.x.x.  and I discovered some hosts

From my local machine, how do I connect to the local address of 10.x.x.x

basically the chain is 127.0.0.1:9999 ... 10.x.x.x:22 ... 192.x.x.x:PortNumber?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use proxychains for this, probably. Ssh has a "jump proxy" option for this:

`ssh -J root@JumpServer root@10.x.x.x`

And you can do multiple jumps if you need to, too:

`ssh -J root@JumpServer,root@10.x.x.x root@192.x.x.x`

You can encode this into your `.ssh/config` for convenience (untested):

```
192.x.x.x
    Username root
    ProxyJump 10.x.x.x

10.x.x.x
    Username root
    ProxyJump JumpServer

JumpServer
    Username root
```

Then `ssh 192.x.x.x` should just work.

I'd use a named alias in '.ssh/config' in addition to the above, but you don't have to:

```
webserver
    Hostname 192.x.x.x
    Username root
    JumpServer 10.x.x.x
```

Now `ssh webserver` should work.